# How to create a tuple with the same shape of another one

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to augment my data for a CCN problem.
I have a csv with 3 image (center, left, right) and a steering angle which is the same for all the three images. (I used the Udacity self driving car simulator).
I want to increase my data, so I'm trying to do augmentation on my image.
I need to create a tuple with a shape like this:

```
image_path = data[["center", "left", "right"]].values
```

But before, I have to augment my data.
That's my code:

```
steerings = data["steering"].values
steerings = list(steerings)
center = data["center"].values
left = data["left"].values
right = data["right"].values
center = list(center)
new_center = []
left = list(left)
new_left = []
right = list(right)
new_right = []
new_steerings = []
for index in range(len(center)):
    new_center_img = augment_image(center[index], steerings[index])[0]
    new_center.append(new_center_img)
    new_left_img = augment_image(left[index], steerings[index])[0]
    new_left.append(new_left_img)
    new_right_img = augment_image(right[index], steerings[index])[0]
    new_right.append(new_right_img)
    new_steerings.append(steerings[index])
center.extend(new_center)
left.extend(new_left)
right.extend(new_right)
steerings.extend(new_steerings)

image_path = tuple(center), tuple(left), tuple(right)
steerings = tuple(steerings)


return train_test_split(image_path, steerings, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

But:

```
image_path = tuple(center), tuple(left), tuple(right)
```

is not the same as:

```
image_path = data[["center", "left", "right"]].values
```

How can I obtain the same thing when I return image path, but with double images due to augmentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you just need to do:

```
image_path = np.stack([center, left, right], axis=1)
```

Where `np` is NumPy.